# Ubuntu 18.04 intel 2d acceleration broken?

Tags: video, 18.04, intel, hardware-acceleration

I upgraded from 17.10 where I had a custom driver [from this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) installed, because otherwise I couldn't get multihead support working on my intel graphics (i7-8700). I removed the drivers from the mentioned ppa because it seems they are not necessary anymore, and everything seems to work fine, except for the animations in GNOME...

looking at `jounalctl -b0` I see things like :

```
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]:         compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]:         ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei gnome-shell[1664]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei gnome-shell[1664]: g_array_unref: assertion 'array' failed
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (EE) modeset(0): eglGetDisplay() failed
mei 18 15:34:05 junpei /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1891]: (EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed
```

I suppose this means 2D acceleration is not working ? does anybody have a clue if and how this can be fixed ? I can provide more info on request...

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems that somewhere in the purging of the old libs, something was uninstalled and never reinstalled. my colleague (having the same problem) found that doing :

```
apt-get install libegl-mesa0
```

fixed it.weird that it didn't get installed as a dependency though.